# Embed tweet in google map infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter

I want to use tweet's embed code and to set that as google map v3 infowindow content and display fully styled tweet iframe on the map. But iframe wont load. I made test case here http://jsfiddle.net/kN7yZ/58/ Click on marker there.

Here is test case code:

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);

var text = '<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>EVO KAŽU DA NAŠA DECA NE VISE TOLIKO NA INTERNETU-PA NE MOGU DA STIGNU OD RODITELJA JEBOTE.</p>&mdash; Nichim Izazvan (@NichimIzazvan) <a href="https://twitter.com/NichimIzazvan/statuses/419180893035827200">January 3, 2014</a></blockquote>';
text += '<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></'+'script>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:text
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}
initialize();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the domready event on the infowindow and add the twitter script from there.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
    ! function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-widgets");
});
```

Remove the script from your infowindow content and leave only the blockquote. See http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/eh4Kp/

You might need to adjust the infowindow size to fit the tweet and I wish you good luck there!

Comment: Thank you, you solved it. I have array of infowindows but when I attach listener to infowindows in loop it does only to last infowindow in array, here is pastebin http://jsfiddle.net/C2AuV/ . Also is there a way to get width/heigth of loaded tweet and then resize infowindow accordingly?

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete. You should not create multiple infowindows. Try to find a way to have only one and set content accordingly. Regarding the size, the width should not be a problem. You could set a min-height on your twitter-tweet class. But that would not be dynamic.

Comment: I left out id setting and checking for script tag, and it is working for array of infowindows. I'll inform more about infowindows styling, and comment that later.